# Error using Canvas to draw simple shapes and cursor coordinates with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, mobile, canvas, touch-event

I am working on a test program that utilized the Canvas onDraw method to draw basic line/shapes and dispense the coordinates of touch event with the onTouch method. Whenever I run the program, it would show an error message of "The application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

Any insight to resolv this problem is very much appreciated!

```
public class CustomDraw extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String text;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        RenderView rv = new RenderView(this);
        rv.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setContentView(rv);

    }
    class RenderView extends View {        
        Paint paint;

    public RenderView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();            
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);            
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, canvas.getWidth()-1, canvas.getHeight()-1, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);            
        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, 40, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(0x770000ff);
        canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 200, 200, paint);

        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawText(text, 10, 25, paint);

        invalidate();
    }
}

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        builder.setLength(0);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            builder.append("down, ");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            builder.append("move, ");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            builder.append("cancle, ");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            builder.append("up, ");
            break;
        }

        builder.append(event.getX());
        builder.append(", ");
        builder.append(event.getY());
        text = builder.toString();
        Log.d("TouchTest", text);

        return true;
    }
}
```

As requested, here's the log result.

```
07-06 01:08:10.520: W/KeyCharacterMap(367): No keyboard for id 0
07-06 01:08:10.520: W/KeyCharacterMap(367): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-06 01:08:12.391: D/AndroidRuntime(367): Shutting down VM
07-06 01:08:12.391: W/dalvikvm(367): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-06 01:08:12.401: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Native Method)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.badlogic.androidgames.CustomDraw$RenderView.onDraw(CustomDraw.java:72)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1114)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-06 01:08:12.411: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 01:08:12.421: I/dalvikvm(367): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-06 01:08:12.421: I/dalvikvm(367): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
07-06 01:08:17.540: I/Process(367): Sending signal. PID: 367 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please give some logcat entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When application is started.

Your String text is not set yet and in your `onDraw` you have this

```
  canvas.drawText(text, 10, 25, paint);
```

This causes `NullPointerException`

From

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/Canvas.java#Canvas.0mNativeCanvas

```
1275    public void drawText(String text, int start, int end, float x, float y,
1276                         Paint paint) {
1277        if ((start | end | (end - start) | (text.length() - end)) < 0) {
1278            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
1279        }
1280        native_drawText(mNativeCanvas, text, start, end, x, y,
1281                        paint.mNativePaint);
1282    }
```

So just initialise your text at the start

```
String text="initial";
```

Comment: @user1450886 what's on line 72?

Comment: canvas.drawText(text, 10, 25, paint);

Comment: @user1450886 try setting `String text="initial"` that should work.

Comment: you have NPE at `canvas.drawText(text, 10, 25, paint)1 your paint object in initialized. the only other explanation can be `text` being null unless i am missing something.

Comment: @user1450886 check if text is null if(text==null){}else{canvas.drawText(text,20,25.paint). also check if paint is null.

Comment: Yes I know, that's the problem. Text is initialized. If I placed any string in there that isn't from onTouch, the application would run fine. But the objective of this is to use onTouch with Canvas, and so far I've been very frustrated trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @user1450886 so then you should not get NPE. and npe is not at `canvas.drawText(text, 10, 25, paint)`.

Comment: OKAY! I solved it!! You're absolutely right the initial of string does the trick. The problem was that the code I had on the IDE had additional debug lines that caused the NPE; I commented those out and it worked well!

Comment: @user1450886 you are welcome also check the source code in the link posted

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this statement into down case when you touch first time. currently it will continue set reset length for your builder in onTouch

```
builder.setLength(0);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        builder.setLength(0);
        builder.append("down, ");
        break;
```